# If $f(z) = z^3$ how is it graphed in the sector $0<arg(z)<\frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: complex-numbers

If $f(z) = (x+yi)(x^2+ 2xyi - y^2) = x^3 -xy^2 -2xy^2 +i(x^2y-y^3+2x^2y) $
How do I know the way it would be graphed in the sector $0<arg(z)<\frac{\pi}{4}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $z=r(\cos \theta+i\sin \theta),$ then $z^3=r^3(\cos \theta+i\sin \theta)^3=r^3(\cos 3\theta+i\sin 3\theta).$ So the image sector under $z\rightarrow z^3$ is $0<\theta<3\pi/4.$

Comment: Where did you get $\frac{3\pi}{2}$?

Comment: It was a typo. Now corrected it.

Comment: Ok, but I was asking in general, how did you arrive at that angle? :)

Comment: For every $\theta$ the image has $3\theta$ amplitude.  See the $\theta$ values in the domain ie $0<\theta<\pi/4$. What are the renge values?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now it's clearer.